# Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ but $g$ is not, then $f$ + $g$ is not differentiable at $a$.

Tags: calculus

I know if two functions, $f$ and $g$, are differentiable at $a$, then so is $f + g$. However, I'm not quite sure how to prove the above.

My first thought was proof by contradiction. So I would suppose $f + g$ is differentiable at $a$. Then, by the above statement, $(f + g)'(a) = f'(a) + g'(a)$. However, I don't know if $g'(a)$ exist.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $a$ then $f+g$ is differentiable  at $a$ and
$$(f+g)'(a)=f'(a)+g'(a)$$

**Hint** Now assume that $f+g$ is differentiable at $a$ and write $g=(f+g)-f$.

Comment: Here's hoping you get a "nice answer" badge for this, perhaps even "enlightened"!

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is by contradiction. Suppose that $f+g$ is differentiable, then $-f+(f+g)=g$ so is. A contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If $f+g$ was differentiable, then since $f$ is differentiable and the difference of two differentiable functions is differentiable, it would follow that $g = (f+g)-f$ is differentiable. Since $g$ is not differentiable, this implies that $f+g$ is not differentiable.